# The placement of "partout" after "peux" followed by the infinitive?

Tags: adverbes, ordre-des-mots

I learned that adverbs usually come after the conjugated verb but what about this:

> Vous pouvez vous garer partout.

Is this more correct: *Vous pouvez partout vous garer.*

Answer (score 3):

*Partout* has a greater connection with *garer* so its expected location is the one of the first sentence. Your second one is still grammatical but less natural. Maybe "You can everywhere park" would be similarly odd.

With a more complex phrase, this location<sup>1</sup> of *partout* would be idiomatic:

> *Vous pouvez, partout et à toute heure, vous garer dans le parking de l'hôtel.*

What would also be possible is:

> *On peut se garer où ?*
> *On peut partout !*

Comment from @Vincent:

With an infinitive, the adverb can be preposed, but it's not very natural for a rhematic word, and therefore, it has en emphasizing effect:

> *Vous pouvez très bien partout faire état de vos opinions, mais je vous suggère de faire attention dans certains lieux.*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>@Vincent rightly commented that my examples cannot be considered to match the requirements as in the first one the phrase *partout et à toute heure* is detached from the rest of the sentence by commas, and in the second one, *se garer* is implicitely located between *peut* and *partout*.</sub>

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Merci, j'avais confondu avec l'expression "With more of a complex[...]"

Comment: Two observations. For `partout et à toute heure`, in your specific example, you cannot say this is the same location as in the original post, since the commas detach the phrase from the rest of the sentence. Also, in `on peut partout`, `partout` is arguably still located after `se garer`, only, the latter remains implicit.

Comment: @Vincent Correct, that's what I suggest with "a more complex phrase". Nobody can say *Je peux partout* absolutely, unless perhaps they are God.

Comment: @Jenni2 Note that with an infinitive, the adverb can be preposed, but it's not very natural for a rhematic word, and therefore, it has en emphasizing effect: "Vous pouvez très bien *partout* faire état de vos opinions, mais je vous suggère de faire attention dans certains lieux."

Comment: @Vincent Merci, j'ai inclus tes commentaires dans ma réponse.